# How to share a variable between two functions in C?

Tags: c, function

In C, suppose var1 is a variable in foo1() and foo2() wants to access var1, however, foo1() doesn't call foo2(), so we can't pass it by parameter. At the same time, only foo1() and foo2() will access it, so I wouldn't like to declare it as global variable. It will be similar with the "friend semantics" in c++, is there any way to implement this in C?

```
void foo1() {
  ... 
  var1;
  ....
}


void foo2() {
 ...
 how to access var1?
 ...
}
```

Comment: "Friend" idea is related to classes and private/protected members. In functions you can only use a global variable. http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-functions-and-global-local-variables

Comment: There is one other way that no ones highlighted in their answer, its the concept of a static global, I wouldn't generally recommend it, but in C, within a C file, if you declare static int var1;  It will only be visible to functions within that file.  so if you had foos.c with those two foo functions, both can access var1, anything outside of the file can't use it.  Still not good, but it is limiting the scope of the global.  Basically in C, public / private / friends is not a supported concept, its basically just a big ol orgy and anyone can poke at anyone elses bits.

Comment: @KeithNicholas yeah.I think static global will do.

Comment: I'd recommend generally not using it though, its just one of those things that often ends up making C code a pain in the ass to maintain / change.

Comment: @ryyker  I'd definitely not recommend that at all.  If you are going to want that kind of thing, I suggest a static global scoped to a file, then a "getter function"  int getVar1()  which you then put in a header file which returns the static global.

Comment: @KeithNicholas - I was simply responding to the criteria given by OP: _1)_ `foo1()`, `foo2()` do not call each other.  _2)_ no function params, _at all_.  I actually like your `struct *` approach.  I do that often to get around growing parameter lists in the front end of a project to avoid having to modify parameter lists. (struct *a, is always struct *a, no matter how many members we add).  But given OP guidelines, I offered up that idea.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you pass the variable to both functions....  in general functions shouldn't hold state.

quickly you find passing variables is not so nice and becomes fragile, so instead, you pass structs.... then functions start working on the state of structs.

```
typedef struct 
{
    int var1;
} blah_t;

void foo1(blah_t* b)
{
    b->var1=0;
}

void foo2(blah_t* b)
{
    b->var1++;
}
```

this is the very simplistic seed idea behind doing OO C.

Comment: I think blah_t is reserved... I guess in POSIX only.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare `var1` outside the scope of the functions and then send it as a parameter to both. Alternatively, declare it as a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

by reference is one way: (in this example the memory for `i` is local to `caller()`)

```
void caller()
{
    int i = 5;
    foo(&i);
    bar(&i);
    printf("\n final i is %d",i);
}

void foo(int *i)
{
    printf("%d",*i);
    *i += 5;
}

void bar (int *i)
{
    printf("%d",*i);
    *i += 5;
}
```

global: (usually considered horrible `i` would have a name more like `GLOBAL_I` or something)

```
int i = 0;

void caller()
{
   i=5;
   foo();
   bar();
   printf("\n final i is %d",i);
}

void foo()
{
   printf("%d",i);
   i += 5;
}

 void bar (int i)
 {
      printf("%d",i);
      i += 5;
 }
```

Comment: (you forgot the semicolons after i += 5)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding *similar with the "friend semantics" in c++*.  C does not have the same capability.
Regarding *so we can't pass it by parameter*

The only option in `C` for accessing a variable from function to function without passing as a function parameter is to use some type of global scope variable.

In the event `void foo1()` and `void foo2()` exist in different C modules...
but you still want to be able to access the same variable, and ensure its value is the same at all times, in all places within your project, then consider using `extern scope`:

Within a header file that is common to both (multiple) modules, a  *project scope global* can be implemented as follows.

***file.h***

```
void foo1(void);
void foo2(void);
extern int var1;
```

***file1.c***

```
#include "file.h"
int var1 = 5; //in only 1 module, declare and initialize the 
              //extern defined in the common header -file.h-

int main(void)
{
    printf("value of var1 is %d\n", var1);//original value of var1
    foo1();
    printf("value of var1 is %d\n", var1);//var1 modified by foo1()
    foo2();
    printf("value of var1 is %d\n", var1);//var1 modified by foo2()
    return 0;
}

void foo1(void)
{
    var1 = 15;//Now that the project global variable
              //has already been declared and defined, it can simply
              //be used, in this file...   
}
```

***file2.c***

```
#include "file.h"

void foo2(void)
{
    var1 = 20;... and in this one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. The variable only exists on the function stack while `foo1()` is running. The stack will vanish when leaving the function. You could make the variable static to keep it alive, but then you can't access it from the outside either without hacks.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is inspired by the 'Module' concept, found in many other languages, which can be approximated using gcc's nested functions. Variable `var1` is within scope for both `foo1()` and `foo2()`, but is out of scope for everything else.  The solution uses neither global vars nor parameters.

```
void foo(int fn)
{
    static int var1;

    void fn1(void)
    {
        var1 = 15;
    }

    void fn2(void)
    {
        var1 = 20;
    }

    (fn == 1)? fn1(): fn2();
    printf("Value of var1 is now %d\n", var1);
}

void foo1(void){foo(1);}
void foo2(void){foo(2);}

int main (void)
{
    foo1();
    // Expected stdout: Value of var1 is now 15

    foo2();
    // Expected stdout: Value of var1 is now 20
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about this line `foo((fn == 1)? fn1(): fn2());` ?

Comment: You edited your Answer, which is good, but even so you have `variable ‘var1’ set but not used |`

Comment: @Michi - Yes, the code merely answered the original question, namely, that 2 functions can exclusively 'see' a common variable, but others cannot.  But for you I'll add a printf() that actually uses var1.

Comment: This is really an awful pattern.