# C function pointers not working - ending programme early

Tags: c, function, pass-by-reference, function-pointers

I have a code with two functions outside of main. I need to pass multiple values from one function to the next. I've tried using pointers and there's no errors when compiling but the programme just ends prematurely. I think this is call by reference but I don't really understand it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int GetRValues (char prompt[70]);

//start main
int main()
{
    char prompt[70]="Please enter a value in the range 1000 to 1000000\0";
    float R_a,R_b,R_c;
    GetRValues(prompt[70]);
    printf("%f, %f, %f", &R_a, &R_b, &R_c);
}
//function for receiving inputs
int GetRValues(char prompt[70])
{
    //declare input variables
    float *R_a;

    //display prompt
    printf("%s\n", prompt);

    //force user to input values for R_a
    printf("R_a = ");
    scanf("%f",&*R_a);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is full programme using pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int GetRValues (char prompt[70], float Rmin, float Rmax);      //declare input function
void ConvertValues(char input,float Ptr_a, float Ptr_b, float Ptr_c);    //declare conversion function
char input;
float Ptr_a, Ptr_b, Ptr_c;

int main()
{
    float Rmin = 1000;
    float Rmax = 1000000;
    char prompt[70]="Please enter a value in the range 1000 to 1000000\0";



    do
    {
        printf("Select operation:\n");
        printf("__________________________\n");
        printf("s: Star to Delta Transformation\n");
        printf("d: Delta to Star Transformation\n");
        printf("q: Exit\n");
        printf("__________________________\n");
        printf("Select: ");
        scanf("%c",&input);


        if (input == 's' || input == 'd')
        {
            GetRValues(prompt,Rmin,Rmax) ==0;
            do
            {
                ConvertValues(input, Ptr_a, Ptr_b, Ptr_c);
                break;
            }

            while (GetRValues(prompt,Rmin,Rmax) ==1);

        }

    }
    while(input != 'q');

    return 0;
}

int GetRValues(char prompt[70], float Rmin, float Rmax)
{
    //declare input variables
    float R_a,R_b,R_c,*Ptr_a,*Ptr_b,*Ptr_c;
    void ConvertValues(char input,float Ptr_a, float Ptr_b, float Ptr_c);
    //display prompt
    printf("%s\n", prompt);

    //force user to input valid values for R_a, R_b and R_c
    printf("R_a = ");
    scanf("%f",&R_a);
    while(R_a>Rmax)
    {
        printf("Please enter a value below %f\n",&Rmax);
        scanf("%f",&R_a);
    }
    while(R_a<Rmin)
    {
        printf("Please enter a value above %f\n",&Rmin);
        scanf("%f",&R_a);
    }


    printf("R_b = ");
    scanf("%f",&R_b);
    while(R_b>Rmax)
    {
        printf("Please enter a value below %f\n",&Rmax);
        scanf("%f",&R_b);
    }
    while(R_b<Rmin)
    {
        printf("Please enter a value above %f\n",&Rmin);
        scanf("%f",&R_b);
    }

    printf("R_c = ");
    scanf("%f",&R_c);
    while(R_c>Rmax)
    {
        printf("Please enter a value below %f\n",&Rmax);
        scanf("%f",&R_c);
    }
    while(R_c<Rmin)
    {
        printf("Please enter a value above %f\n",&Rmin);
        scanf("%f",&R_c);
    }
    //transferring values to pointers
    *Ptr_a = R_a;
    *Ptr_b = R_b;
    *Ptr_c = R_c;
    printf("%f",&Ptr_a);
    return 1;
}
void ConvertValues(char input, float Ptr_a, float Ptr_b, float Ptr_c)
{
 float R_a,R_b,R_c,R_1,R_2,R_3;
    if (input ==  's')
    {
        R_1=(Ptr_a*Ptr_b)+(Ptr_b*Ptr_c)+(Ptr_a*Ptr_c)/Ptr_c;
        R_2=(Ptr_a*Ptr_b)+(Ptr_b*Ptr_c)+(Ptr_a*Ptr_c)/Ptr_b;
        R_3=(Ptr_a*Ptr_b)+(Ptr_b*Ptr_c)+(Ptr_a*Ptr_c)/Ptr_a;

        printf("The resistance values in Delta: \n");
        printf("Ptr_a = %.2f Ohms\n",R_1);
        printf("Ptr_b = %.2f Ohms\n",R_2);
        printf("Ptr_c = %.2f Ohms\n",R_3);
    }
 else
    {
        R_1=(Ptr_a*Ptr_b)/Ptr_a+Ptr_b+Ptr_c;
        R_2=(Ptr_a*Ptr_c)/Ptr_a+Ptr_b+Ptr_c;
        R_3=(Ptr_b*Ptr_c)/Ptr_a+Ptr_b+Ptr_c;

        printf("The resistance values in Star: \n");
        printf("Ptr_a = %.2f Ohms\n",R_1);
        printf("Ptr_b = %.2f Ohms\n",R_2);
        printf("Ptr_c = %.2f Ohms\n",R_3);


    }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to use pointers? Could `GetRValues` return a struct with the values you want to use, and `ConvertValues` take that struct as an argument?

Comment: Depending on what you plan on doing with this code in the future, declaring the R_ variables outside the function scope would work too.

Comment: The R_ variables are defined in main, I just don't know how to pass values from the function. And I'm not sure how to do that with struct either. I've added the whole code for reference

Comment: I get the impression that an actual [mre] for demonstrating your problem would be more minimal...

Comment: Okay, here's a simplified version. Using pointers means the programme crashes.

Comment: `GetRValues(prompt[70])` should cause a compilation error -- if you don't see an error message then fix your compiler settings before doing anything else, as it is causing you to waste time by having them set wrong

Comment: @josjammet Some hints to help you progress. There no "pass by reference" arguments in C. Compile with `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` flags, it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Any variable that you define within a function like the `R_a`, `R_b` and `R_c` in your `GetRValues()` function are *local*, meaning after the execution of this function on the processor these values are removed. To use them in another function you either have to declare `R_a`, `R_b` and `R_c` as `global` outside of `GetRValues()` or you can define a `struct` `R` in that you store `R_a`, `R_b`, `R_c` and fill this struct inside `GetRValues()` and then access it by giving the same struct to `ConvertValues()` as parameter like in [How to share a variable between two functions in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254055/how-to-share-a-variable-between-two-functions-in-c)  (global variables are bad practice, if you use the *struct* approach in combination with if you use multiple threads you have to protect the struct by mutexes / semaphores)

If you want to use pointers you have to call `ConvertValues()` inside of `GetRValues()` like in *Grady Player*'s answer in [How to share a variable between two functions in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254055/how-to-share-a-variable-between-two-functions-in-c) , because as said variables defined inside of functions are only local

Comment: Thank you, calling ConvertValues() inside of GetRValues() allows that function to work correctly with pointers. Only problem now is that it doesn't move on to the next function.

Comment: The person asking the question knows so little about C that global variables seem to be the best solution for them.

Comment: I'm know enough to know I should avoid using global variables

Answer (score 0):

What ypu need is to LEARN how to use pointers to pass values into functions. In the C language pointers are the standard means of passing values to functions in such a way that the functions can modify them. In other words, if you intend to write a function that reads some values from the user and then sends them to somewhere else in the program, the normal way in C is by using pointers.

I haven't found anything relevant on StackOverflow about this absolutely basic issue. You can search yourself the internet for "C language function argument pass by pointer" etc. Here's one such find: https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/c-passing-pointers-to-functions/

In your case, the  function that wants to pass values to the outside world must be taking them by pointers, e.g. like this:

```
int GetRValues(char prompt[70], float* Rmin, float* Rmax)
```

This requires that  the body of the function will be changed adequately, for now you have pointers to floats rather than floats. To this end, replace each
occurrence of `Rmin` with `*Rmin`, and `Rmax` with `*Rmax`. However, whenever there's  `&Rmin`, it suffices to write `Rmin` (& cancel out with *). Of course do this transformation only inside this single function.

Now you have a function that accepts pointers as arguments. This require changing the way it is called. For example, oh no, you've just edited your code, you've made it WORSE, I cant' give you an example! Ok, I'll try.

Instead of

```
GetRValues(prompt[70]);
```

use

```
GetRValues(prompt, &R_a, &R_b, &R_c);
```

This will not work, eh, because you edit your code all the time and nobody knows what you want to achieve. A few minutes ago you wanted to read 2 numbers, now 3. Please decide. Please read about pointers in C and how to use them to pass values to, and especially FROM functions.